# Is it acceptable to use pointers to class as enum constants?

Tags: c++

Say I have some global objects:

```
MyClass* a = new MyClass()
MyClass* b = new MyClass()
MyClass* c = new MyClass()
```

Which repesent all meaningful states of `MyClass`

Is there a good reason not to form an enum from them as follows?

```
enum MyEnum {
    A = (int) a,
    B = (int) b,
    C = (int) c
}
```

Such that in other code, I can pass the enum around, and cast it: `(MyClass*) (MyEnum::A)`

Comment: Should enum store values? Isn't it meant to represent state?.. And if it was possible, how would you handle memory leak? Hey, I'm a noob at C++ so I'd like to know

Comment: Compile this code and you will get the answer automatically.

Comment: @LewsTherin: I was trying to associate data with state

Comment: @iammilind: Whoops, I guess I simplified my problem poorly. In fact, the pointers are to addresses known at compile time (memory-mapped peripherals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't work. Enumerators can only be initialised with constant expressions, which your variables `a`, `b`, `c` definitely are not.

Answer (score 2):

enum values are compile time constants, where as the return values of new are runtime values, as such you can not even do that (plus you would likely loose some data in the cast to int). I don't think it makes sense for SO to go into a lengthy discussion about whether it would be a good idea or not if it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

As others already said, this is not possible. But you could achieve something similar with a singleton pattern, e.g.:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    enum MyEnum { A, B, C };

    static MyClass* getAInstance()
    {
        static MyClass* a = new MyClass();
        return a;
    }

    static MyClass* getBInstance()
    {
        static MyClass* b = new MyClass();
        return b;
    }

    static MyClass* getCInstance()
    {
        static MyClass* c = new MyClass();
        return c;
    }

    static MyClass* getInstance(MyEnum instance)
    {
        switch(instance)
        {
        case A:
            return getAInstance();
        case B:
            return getBInstance();
        case C:
            return getCInstance();
        }
    }
};
```

So instead of `(MyClass*) (MyEnum::A)` you would write `MyClass::getInstance(MyClass::A)`.

Comment: Is it necessary to declare the local variables there?

Comment: Not necessary per se, but that's how you usually implement a singleton pattern in C++. This is preferable to having raw global objects. Note: The variables are not local, but static!

Comment: Does the constructor get called every time I invoke `getCInstance()` (is `static MyClass* c = new MyClass();` equivalent to `static MyClass* c; c = new MyClass();`), or does it execute just once?

Comment: The constructor is only executed once

Answer (score 0):

I'm curius: why you need this implementation? 
By the way, I suggest you to use a vector/array with function pointer, if you need something for loop.